# How to refresh table view on button click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsurlsession

I want to change the url of an nsurlsession call on click of a button and refresh the tableView immediately here is what i have so far

```
    @IBAction func d(sender: AnyObject) {

    url = NSURL(string: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/coDxrSkrNe?indent=2")!

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            do {
                if let restaurants = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {



                    let names = restaurants.flatMap { $0["preferred_name"] as? String }
                    let time = restaurants.flatMap { $0["cooking_time"] as? String }


                    for restaurant in restaurants {
                        if let name = restaurant["preferred_name"] as? String {
                            let cookingTime = ""
                            let food = Food(name: name, time:cookingTime)
                            self.food.append(food)
                        }
                    }



                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }

                    print(names)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()

    self.tableView.reloadData()


}
```

Here is what my code looks like now but the tableView is still not reloading or changing the data after clicking the button

Comment: You have it right, but you need to call `reloadData` when you get your response back from the server.

Comment: What problem are you having with the posted code? FYI - there is no reason to use `dispatch_async` here. Your `d` function will only be called on the main thread.

Comment: The tableview is not reloading @rmaddy

Comment: @Harsh yes i called reloadData after the response but the tableView wont still change the data

Comment: Is the call to `reloadData` being reached? And why do you expect to see any changes anyway? You haven't updated anything about the datasource.

Comment: Updated the datasource?

Comment: Update the Array which you are using in `cellForRowAtIndex`

Comment: Can i update this from the function f because i already called cellForRowAtIndex

Comment: Simply setting `url` doesn't do anything. You need code that accesses that URL and processes the results and then updates the data used to populate the table view. Then you should call `reloadData`.

Comment: Ok so basically i can create annother function to make another nsurlsession call

Comment: Yes, make function to get the data from the server with the URL you updated. On completion of your request, update the data source for table view and then `reloadData`

Comment: Can u make an example of this because i already tried this

Comment: @Harsh I updated the question here is my code now

Comment: @Shaggy1_0 Are you facing any problems with this now?

Comment: Yes The table is still not changing data

Comment: @Harsh Can u help?

Comment: Give me a couple of mins. I'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/harsh62/stackoverflow_insert_dynamic_rows

I have created a dummy project, click on refresh and see that the data is added to the table View. I have used the same function which you created but added to my own data source. The only new thing i had to do was to allow arbitrary loads for the project.

If your app (a third-party web browser, for instance) needs to load arbitrary content, Apple provides a way to disable ATS altogether, but I suspect it’s wise for you to use this capability sparingly:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

If you are facing something like this then here is another place which you can checkout 
[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Reinitialize the array like this.

```
self.names = [];
for restaurant in restaurants {
    if let name = restaurant["preferred_name"] as? String {
        self.names.append(name)
    }
}
```

Comment: lol.. sorry about that. forgot to push the changes. Done now.

Comment: It is inserting new rows i want to replace it with the new content not add the new content

Comment: If you check i am inserting it deliberately to show you that the tableView is reloading itself.

Comment: So how can i get this to replace the data there before

Comment: In the sample project, I have used `self.names.append(name)`. Instead of this, create a new `Array`, add your data coming from the server and then assign it to `self.food` in your case.

Comment: If i want to remove the old array and replace with the new one

Comment: Yeah. it's pretty straight forward. May be the table view is reloading itself but there is no new data to see.

Comment: Ok so now each time i click the button new data is poped to the bottom of the table but what i want is to remove the old data and replace it with the new ones coming in

Comment: ` self.names = [];
                        for restaurant in restaurants {
                            if let name = restaurant["preferred_name"] as? String {
                                self.names.append(name)
                            }
                        }`  Use it like this. reinitialize the array.

Comment: How can i contact u if i have any issue

Comment: Great. You can accept the answer and close this thread. Lots of comments. And yeah you can contact me on my email. harsh.batth@gmail.com

Comment: I just followed u on github

Comment: Am unable to accept answer seems my reputation is too low